# Use a function for templateURL in AngularJS with Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following:

```
export class MyComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public static componentName: string = "myViewer";

    public bindings: any;
    public controller: any;
    public controllerAs: any;
    public templateUrl: string;

    constructor() {
        this.bindings = {
            configName: '@'
        };

        this.controllerAs = "ctrl";
        this.controller = MyController;
        this.templateUrl = 'scripts/components/my-viewer/my-viewer.html';
    }

}
```

I want to be able to specify the templateURL dynamically, by including it in the bindings:

```
this.bindings = {
                configName: '@',
                templateURL: '=?'
            };
```

And then using a function for templateURL (see https://ng-table.com/api-docs/interfaces/angular.icomponentoptions.html)

In a pre-typescripted version of the code I could do something like:

```
templateUrl: function ($element, $attrs) {
      return '<SomeLogicToChooseTheTemplate>';
    }
```

How can I make something similar work in the Typescript version?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
this.templateURL = function(elem: IAugmentedjQuery, attrs: Iattributes) : string {
    return '<SomeLogicToChooseTheTemplate>';
}
```